# Code not sending request to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I have got a problem with sending a request from my app. I am using phonegap build solution here and one of the plugins - push notifications. The code is below:

```
 function tokenHandler(result) {
         var channelid;
         if (subParam == 2) {
            channelid = '2';
            } else if (subParam == 4) {
            channelid = '4,5';
            } else if (subParam == 1){
            channelid = '3';
            } else {
            channelid = '1';
            } 

            var url = "http://server.com/";
            var params = "device_token=" + result + "&device_type=ios&channels_id=" + channelid;
            http.open("POST", url, true);

            //Send the proper header information along with the request
            http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
            http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
            http.send(params);

        alert("channel: " + channelid + "token: " + result);
    }
```

The variable **subParam** is located in a separate `<script>` in header. I think there is a problem with request but may be wrong. Even alert is not firing but if I move above IF the alert is working fine. Thank you for your expertise here.

Comment: Try adding `console.debug('subParam', subParam)` before the `if` to actually see what `subParam` is.

Comment: java <> javascript ..

Comment: thank you atomman but it seems it cannot pick the subParam at all for some reason. can you suggest any thing else please?

Comment: is subParam visible from a global scope? I mean, if you define subParam in a separate script but it is defined inside a function, it will not be seen by this function.  You may need to move its definition.  Maybe you can add a summary of where/how subParam is defined?

Comment: Thanks blurfus it is defined in a script not inside a function. But some functions cannot get it for some reasons. How can I make it global?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot suggest how to make it global since I have no idea how it is defined.  Maybe if you can post a summary of how/where it is defined?

Comment: just inside script above as var subParam = "2";

Comment: is the other script tag added before or after your script tag? (hint: should be declared before you can call or use it)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46458/discussion-between-blurfus-and-qqruza)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I supposed you can also pass `subParam` as a parameter to your function. Like:

```
function tokenHandler(result, subParam){

   if (subParam == '2') {
     // rest of code ...
   }
     // rest of code ...
```

**Update Based on CHAT**

Start by comparing subParam == '2' (as string) since that's how it is defined elsewhere.

Final solution includes changing to making the call as AJAX as this:

The ajax should be:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: url+params, 
    type: 'GET', 
    data: {'device_token': results, 'device_type': 'ios', ...[all parameters here] }, 
    success: function (result, status, XHR) { 
        alert(XHR.status); 
    }, 
    error: function () { 
        alert("error"); 
    } 
});
```

([Chat Transcript][1])
[1]: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/46458 "chat transcript"

Comment: it doesn't help unfortunately

Comment: that's odd!, does it have a value when it is passed in? As in, can you copy/paste the output of `console.debug('subParam', subParam);` as @atomman suggested